# Input Text In InternetExplorer Causes Wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. The requirement is that there is a field called 'amount' which should not
exceed a length of 13 characters. If it exceeds then the text will be highlighted in red.

Everything works fine, but when I type in more than 20 characters in the textbox, the textbox breaks into a new line. The textbox is inside a TD.

Can someone guide me how to avoid the breaking of form ?

Comment: where is the code ? create a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `maxlength="13"` to avoid that brake.